# Is there any advantage to ImageButton over Button?

Tags: asp.net

Since a `Button` can have a background image and also text, what's the point of an `ImageButton`?

(I'm thinking of changing `ImageButton`s to simple `Button`s, and want to know if there's any disadvantage to that.)

Comment: Which property of [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) sets the background image? Of course you can use CSS to let your button look like an ImageButton, but why don't you want to use the correct control in the first place?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `CssClass="myimage"` And
`.myimage
{
    background-image: url('...');
}`

Comment: Yes, as i've mentioned. But since you want to use server controls, you should use the correct server control in the first place. The behaviour of `Button` might change in future releases of ASP.NET.

Comment: I need the text. And rather have real text than make an image with text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one - With `ImageButton` I can refer to a url as **~/** myImage.jpg. I can't do that with a regular `Button`.

This is important when using a master page - because the relative path to a url can be different for different pages if they're in different directories.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put:

- `Button` renders as `<input type="submit" />`
- `ImageButton` renders as `<input type="image" />`

The difference between the two, in terms of accessibility, are mentioned here:

http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/6-button-submit.html

Comment: So it seems there's no disadvantage to `Button` compared to `ImageButton`. Correct?

Comment: @ispiro No I don't think so. They just render as 2 different `input` `type` elements.